Vertica multiple datasets union Why is it so slow?
I have two more datasets, one dataset data has millions of data, and one dataset has only a few data, it takes usually more than ten minutes to unionize these two datasets, why is it like this, is there any optimization solution?
select * from tableA ----- million data
union all
select * from tableB ----- 10 pieces of data
Any data set query is fast
but it's slow when two datasets are united.

Your problem might be caused by any reasons. 2 obvious to me are:

Performance issues - I don't know where you've deployed your db instance so It might not have enough power and you need to increase your db memory/cpu.

Not optimized query/DDL (My tip)



since you didn't mentioned anything about the tables I don't know much but I'd check several things:

There are PKs in the tables. Are there PK in specified in those tables DDL?
Are there valid projections? You should order projection regarding the PK.
More about projections can be find in the Vertica docs here - https://docs.vertica.com/23.3.x/en/admin/projections/creating-projections/.



Everytime I struggled with performance in Vertica db there was some problem with the right Order of projections or PK implementation. I hope this helps
Martin
